# Pass multiple -classpath options to the java command

Tags: java, jar

In some script I would like to have

```
java -cp base:class:path "$@"
```

where `"$@"` may be a complete set of `java` command line options with additional `-cp` options, think `... -cp this.jar:that.jar -Dsome.prop=1 ... some.package.Main`. But additional `-cp` options override the previous one. I wildly guessed things like `-cp +...` or `-cp :...` in the hope to have them added, but this does not work.

Is there some trick I am missing, apart from looping over `"$@"` and injecting the `base:class:path`?

Comment: There is no such thing, but I wonder, wouldn't base:class:path:$@ work?

Comment: No. Extended the question to be clearer in this regard.